# Print all the row with two or more element in the column

Tags: database-design, join, union, dbms, relational-algebra

In following table how to print the student number when age occur two or more times, The result should be only column `Sno` i.e. 
**Result**

| Sno | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | because 18 occur two times |
| 2 | because 20 occur three times |
| 4 | because 20 occur three times |
| 6 | because 20 occur two times |
| 8 | because 18 occur two times |
| 10 | because 18 occur two times |

**Student Table**

| Sno | Sname | Smarks | Sage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 90 | 18 |
| 2 | B | 94 | 20 |
| 3 | C | 87 | 21 |
| 4 | D | 95 | 20 |
| 5 | E | 97 | 19 |
| 6 | F | 80 | 20 |
| 7 | G | 85 | 22 |
| 8 | H | 96 | 17 |
| 9 | I | 84 | 20 |
| 10 | J | 93 | 18 |

Comment: What database system and version are you using,?...as that affects what answers are applicable, so please tag them.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Answer (score -1):

Given the following set of data:

[image]

First, we want to find out how many times a given age occurred for each row.

Using an aggregate function with GROUP BY will result in reduction of rows, which is not what we want.

```sql
SELECT age, COUNT(id)
FROM students
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY age ASC
```

[image] We don't want this.

Instead, we could use window functions to count how many times a given age occurred for each row. We can use window functions for that. Window functions operates on a set of rows, without reducing the number of rows. The condition is specified by the "PARTITION BY" keyword.

```sql
SELECT id, age, COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY age) AS occurrence
FROM students
```

[image] We want this.

[Read about window functions here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/)

Now, according to the requirements, we only want to select the records where age occurred 2 times or more (> 1). So simply wrapping it up in a CTE and filter out the records where the occurrence is > 1 will give you the final results.

[Read about common table expression here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/)

```sql
WITH duplicate_age_cte AS (
    SELECT id, age, COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY age) AS occurrence
    FROM students
)
SELECT cte.id, cte.age, ('because ' || cte.age || ' occurs ' || cte.occurrence || ' times') AS reason
FROM duplicate_age_cte cte
WHERE cte.occurrence > 1
ORDER BY cte.id ASC
```

Results

[image]

```sql
('because ' || cte.age || ' occurs ' || cte.occurrence || ' times') AS reason
```

This is just to display the column in a human readable format, according to the requirements.

The steps above are my thought process leading to the final results.

I apologize for bad English, not a native speaker.

Comment: Would you mind adding some context around what your query is doing and why you believe this is the correct answer?

Comment: Updated. Thank you. @BrendanMcCaffrey